# Is there a way to access Skype IM logs?

Tags: chat, logging, skype

I tried looking in C:\Users[name]\AppData\Roaming\Skype and I found a folder called "chatsync" with some mysterious folders with files ending in .dat.  I'm almost certain that these are the chat logs but I don't know a way to properly open these files (notepad shows gibberish mixed with English words).  I'm not trying to do sleuthing, just a project for my girlfriend.

So more importantly: how can I read Skype's .dat files properly?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/skype_log_view.html

Comment: -1: The program reads the log files as requested, but returns them in such a useless format (one long sortable list of granular entries) that any .dat reader would be almost as useful. [Roman's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10789049/356541) ([Skyperious](http://suurjaak.github.com/Skyperious/)) actually provides a useful view and navigation tool.

Comment: That's proprietary.

Answer (score 22):

There is a new, awesome app [Skyperious](http://suurjaak.github.com/Skyperious/); 
Skyperious can:

- open local Skype SQLite databases and look at their contents:
- search across all messages and contacts
- browse, filter and export chat histories, see chat statistics
- view any database table and and export their data
- change, add or delete data in any table
- execute direct SQL queries

Comment: Two years and a day later, people are still coming to my rescue.

Comment: +1: This app fulfills the implicit requirement of parsing the logs and pushing them through to a view which is actually much cleaner and more functional than Skype's native interface (filter by time period etc). Note that the Windows installer fails silently unless explicitly run as administrator.

Comment: This worked for me, but I only was able to download the last 6 months, despite seeing nearly 2 years in Skype itself.  Also, it asked for a password, then wasn't able to log in to Skype, which made me nervous.

Comment: Skyperious is a beautiful app, you can see chat history from the beginning of time. You have change its time period filter available in the right panel of the Chats tab. I can see my entire chat history for more than 3 years. You can also export it to a html file It asked for password only to download shared images from Skype server. If you suspect you mayn't give password. You still able to see your chat history.

Comment: Just downloaded and installed; doesn´t seem to find any data in the file. New DB format for Skype or wrong DB file (`%AppData%/Local/Packages/Microsoft.SkypeApp_<gibberish>_/LocalState/<gibberish>_<skypeusername>.db`)?

Answer (score 2):

You can also install [SQLite for windows](http://www.sqlite.org/download.html). Messages are stored as a SQLite database (several tables exist in the db - the 'Messages' table holds chat messages).

Comment: This one must be a preferred answer.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a fairly old thread, but I figured add some extra info,

I didn't really like the way the **NirSoft Skype Log View** is able to export the chat messages, so I kinda hacked together my own parser for it for fun - but I was slightly lazy to add it to any kind of source control mechanism, which might seem awkward, but that's okay.

http://www.mediafire.com/download/yp0r3r5c686ecrk/SkypeMessageParser.zip

I have included the JAR file and the source.

It takes the text file export of Skype Log View (created by the following command)

```
SkypeLogView.exe /SaveDirect /UseTimeRange 0 /logsfolder "C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Skype\skypeusername" /stext "C:\Root\Downloads\skypelogview\log.txt"
```

which has the data format of this:

```
==================================================

Record Number     : 110

Action Type       : Chat Message

Action Time       : 2012.06.04. 22:31:08

End Time          : 

User Name         : l__i

Display Name      : N___L

Duration          : 

Chat Message      : messagegoeshere

ChatID            : #skypeid/$hashcode

Filename          : 

==================================================
```

And converts it into this:

```
[2012.06.04. 22:31:08] l_i (N___L): messagegoeshere
```

And it also takes the Chat ID and cuts the log up based on that into multiple files, so the chats don't end up mixing together.

For example,

```
  2012-06-05--l__i-z_n.txt (where the date is the date of the first message).
```

**Usage:**

```
java -jar SkypeMessageParser.jar [path of exported TXT file from SkypeLogViewer] [absolute path of output TXT file]
```

I hope someone finds this useful! :)

**Note:** the program expects a system date format of `yyyy.MM.dd` meaning it will *crash* if you have the format of `dd/MM/yyyy`.

Comment: Please note that it relies on using a date format in the form of yyyy.MM.dd. as per system settings, because of the String operations I used which were extremely simplistic.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no way to open those files except with a utility.  I've always used this one to read them:

http://www.osiwanlan.de/skypr/