# skype: how to read chat message using main.db

Tags: sqlite, skype

I have tried upto a level but after that I am stuck. Let share steps I followed:

1. I can see `main.db` file at this location `C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Roaming\Skype\paul.lowry198`.
2. To open this `main.db` file I have installed [SQL Lite BB Browser](http://sqlitebrowser.org/) application.
3. This application can show all existing tables in DB. There is one table `chats`. On this table I am firing a query `select * from Chats where friendlyname = 'Jimmy Trevor';` It resulted 69 results.
4. Now after this how to read the message that he wrote but deleted(or any message) before I could read it.

What could be the correct query that can show me the message?

Answer (score 13):

I've done this 4 years ago and today I need that again.

So after opening main.db file using SQLite Browser you need to:

Determine id of conversation (one person could be in multiple conversations):

```
select conv_dbid, * from Chats where friendlyname like '%Friendly Name%';
```

OR you can find desired conversation id using

```
select * from Conversations where identity like '%accountname%';
```

**Finally, SQL Query to get all messages from desired conversation:**

```
select body_xml, datetime(timestamp, 'unixepoch'), edited_by, edited_timestamp 
from Messages where convo_id=YOUR_CONVERSATION_ID;
```

Unfortunately I discovered that **main.db** fields body_xml, edited_by and edited_timestamp changed every time person editing/deleting message and **there is no backup of body_xml in main.db**.

---

But don't worry! There is a folder **chatsync** near main.db database (in your skype account folder /AppData/Roaming/Skype/Account_Name_Folder).

All messages in **chatsync** is in Skype binary format, to read them you can use lightweight free utility http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/skype_log_view.html

Here is the start dialog of SkypeLogView, it automatically selects your skype directory (better close your skype application, but it is not necessary). Choose dates to faster up search process.

[image: SkypeLogView start dialog]
Voila!

Answer (score 2):

Note that as of April 2017 and the new Skype for Windows 10 (Skype UWP - Universal Windows Platform), the `main.db` file has moved to

`%localappdata%\Packages\Microsoft.SkypeApp_kzf8qxf38zg5c\LocalState\<SkypeUsername>\main.db`

with `%localappdata%` being `C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Local`

Comment: ...and it also looks like the internal sqlite3 database scheme has been reshuffled quite substantially.

Answer (score 0):

**Browse and export your Skype history online**

I recently used the following platform :
http://www.skypebrowser.com/ (*UPDATE* the domain is down)

**Steps**

1. Click to upload your Skype database (Max 30 MB).
   [find main.db from local disk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgD0c.png)

Find the main.db file:
C:\Users<WindowsUserName>\AppData\Roaming\Skype<SkypeUserName>\main.db

wait a couple minutes to upload the file:
[Uploaded main.db file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQqLm.png)

2. After open file, you can export as html zip file to your local disk, with export button. [Export as zipped html file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOsjN.png)
3. Save as the file.
   [Save as the zip file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kMTTO.png)

Inside zip file, exist all conversations with people or groups in different html files.