# Get Skype chat history from main.db synced to MySQL with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, skype

Is there a way to get with PHP maybe from Skype main.db data copied to MySQL in every X minutes?

I have Windows 10 and WAMP server running.

Comment: Please show us your approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have WAMPP running then just create a BAT file:

```
copy /b/v/y C:\Users\YOURNAME\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.SkypeApp_kzf8qxf38zg5c\LocalState\s4l-YOUR_SKYPE_NAME.db C:\wamp64\www\skype.db
```

Then you have the DB file accessible with PHP

```
$db = new SQLite3('skype.db');
$results = $db->query('SELECT nsp_data FROM messagesv12');
while ($row = $results->fetchArray()) {
// And here's the data:
// $messages['cuid']
// $messages['conversationId']
// $messages['creator']
// $messages['createdTime']
// $messages['content']
}
```

Just do whatever you want with the data. Add to MySQL or whatever you wish.

Comment: Do you use Win10? I can't seem to find db file at that location.

Comment: I have Windows 10, yes